# Mirroring Firebase Documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a Firebase group-chat like app using firestore. Currently, I have a Groups collection with a document for each group chat in my app. I also add the group document to any user in that group. I was wondering whether it's possible to create links between identical documents so that firestore automatically updates the group document that the user has in a sub collection whenever the group document in the Groups collection is updated

```
Firestore
|---Groups
    |---GroupDocument: abcdef
|---Users
   |---UserDocument: 12345
       |---Groups
           |--- GroupDocument: abcdef
```

Basically when Firestore/Groups/abcdef is updated, is there a way to set up firestore to automatically update Firestore/Users/12345/Groups/abcdef? I'm looking to avoid using cloud functions for this, but would be open to using it if thats the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore will not do that for you.  Your code will have to make sure any data is correctly duplicated.  You could do that in your client code, or write code to do that in response to a single write using [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) to detect the change and update the other documents.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try using Recycler views; https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

2.in the model view arrange the ui to display the user value in a format that can be displayed as lists

3. Set an Auth Listener in Your package to directly Query changes made to Firebase directly into your project:

   Button.setOnClickListener {
   startActivity(Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java))
   finish()
   }
4. In firebase, Display your database in the said order you prefer for easier viewing. in the option bar of a Collection. Set your groups as the Collection and the Message receipts as the documents